# Слайд шоу на сайте с таблицей изображений

Tags: jquery, html, javascript, html5

Всем привет!
Я опять со своей таблицей фотографий.)
имеется таблица с фотографиями и библиотека chop slider на jquery.
[Вот что должно получиться примерно](http://ruseller.com/lessons/les1456/demo/index.html)
.
но вместо интерфейса управление кнопками я делаю таблицу с изображениями. если выстроить изображения в ряд (то есть через одну `<tr>...</tr>`) то все впорядке, но когда строчек много ничего не выходит.
вот исходники:
HTML:

---

```
<div id="slider">
<div class="slide cs-activeSlide">
<img src="9e06c4_6.jpg"/ > </div>
<div class="slide ">
<img src="a1fb853_6.jpg"/ > </div>
<div class="slide ">
<img src="c72_6.jpg"/ > </div>
<div class="slide ">
<img src="e2bcc122000a1fa49d_6.jpg"/ > </div>
<table class="pagination">
<tr>
<td><img src="e2bcc122000a1fa49d_6.jpg"/ ></td>
<td><img src="e2bcc122000a1fa49d_6.jpg"/ ></td>
<td><img src="e2bcc122000a1fa49d_6.jpg"/ ></td>
<td><img src="e2bcc122000a1fa49d_6.jpg"/ ></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

### JavaScript

(кусок кода, полный код [здесь](http://ruseller.com/lessons/les1456/demo/css/chopslider.css))

```
        b.sliderPagination && (c(b.sliderPagination).eq(c(b.activeQClass).index()).addClass(b.activePaginationClass), c(b.sliderPagination).click(function(d) {
            d.preventDefault();
            var d = c(this), a = c(b.activeQPaginationClass).index();
            if (!d.hasClass(b.activePaginationClass))
                clearTimeout(c.chopSlider.autoplay), b.autoplay = !1, a = d.index() > a ? "next" : "prev", w(a, b, d.index())
        }))
```

Comment: надеюсь как обычно на помощь @eicto XDDDD )))

Answer (score 3):

Я предлагаю вместо таблиц, использовать ссылки - картинки. Привожу кусок кода

---

```
<ul id="photos">
        <li><a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/brockwhittaker/8500935165/" style="background-image:url(http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8233/8500935165_2835685f30.jpg)">Что-то 5</a></li>
```

---

CSS

---

```
#photos li a{
    position:absolute;
    top:6px;
    left:6px;
    right:6px;
    bottom:6px;
    background-size: cover;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

---

Пример полностью можно увидеть здесь http://originalip.ru/?L=48 скачай пример и загляни в index.html и стили, там всё очень просто. А на счёт таблиц... думаю что самому table можно задать ширину, а td inline, по идее это поможет, но ведь с ссылками куда проще, ведь они будут выступать как миниатюра.

Comment: отлично. вы гений.